# Ctrl+Alt+O (Organize Imports) not working on Intellij IDEA

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, intellij

I can't use the shortcut for **Organize Imports** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> action for **Intellij IDEA** on **Ubuntu 14.04**.

Note - I'm just posting it to help someone to avoid wasting time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was that I had `ClipIt 1.4.2` installed and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is set by default to the Off-line Mode hot-key.

As @mounir indicates in its comment, `gpaste gnome-extension` also has the same shortcut.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had this installed and had forgotten. I wish there was a way to see what programs were swallowing bound keys like that.

Comment: For me it was gpaste gnome-extension, thanks